# binding event handler to custom object

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, binding

How can I bind event handler to the custom object that i created?

here is my XAML

```
 <ListBox x:Name="ListData">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,30">
                                    <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{Binding Path=TileImage}" Width="175" Height="175" />
                                    <TextBlock  Margin="5" Width="200" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=TileName}" FontSize="25"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>            
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

Code Behind

```
    // Create collection
    ImageTiles = new ObservableCollection<ImageTile>();

    // Create each object in the collection
    ImageTile RSS= new ImageTile("RSS", "/Images/Hard.jpg");
    ImageTile test= new ImageTile("test", "/Images/Hard.jpg");
    ImageTile Exam= new ImageTile("Exam", "/Images/Hard.jpg");
    ImageTile Settings = new ImageTile("Settings", "/Images/Hard.jpg");

    ImageTiles.Add(RSS);
    ImageTiles.Add(test);
    ImageTiles.Add(Exam);
    ImageTiles.Add(Settings);

    this.ListData.ItemsSource = ImageTiles;
```

I would like to bind the event handler along with each ImageTile. Any idea how to do so? =)

Comment: I might have missed it, but what Event handler are you trying to bind to?

Comment: @Robaticus    I just wish to bind different event to different imageTile. Like 1st imagetile called as RSS, when user click on the RSS icon then it should navigate to some page while 2nd imagetile should navigate to another page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code structure I'll answer assuming you're not using MVVM or the like, however I'd definitely recommend that pattern for Silverlight development.

Nevertheless, your datasource binding would be something like:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListData" ItemsSource="{Binding ImageTiles}">

</ListBox>
```

You could create a single generic click handler in your code behind and assign the Image's click event to that handler.

```
<ImageButton VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{Binding Path=TileImage}" Width="175" Height="175" Click="imageButton_Click" />
```

You could then have a method on your object responsible for redirecting to whatever necessary place for that particular image tile. Then in your code behind handler would resemble this:

```
private void imageButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var imageTile = ((ImageButton)sender).DataContext as ImageTile;
    imageTile.RedirectSomewhere();
}
```

Comment: No worries. I able to binding the item along. I just wish to bind different event to different imageTile. Like 1st imagetile called as RSS, when user click on the RSS icon then it should navigate to some page while 2nd imagetile should navigate to another page

Comment: Thanks for your reply =) 
Everything seem great now.

Answer (score 1):

In your ViewModel, add a property to capture selected item (e.g.)

```
private ImageTile _selectedItem;
public ImageTile SelectedItem
{
     get {return _selectedItem;}
     set
     {
         if(value != _selectedItem)
         { 
              _selectedItem = value;
              RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
         }
     }
}
```

Then, in your XAML, bind the SelectedItem:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ImageTiles}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
</ListBox>
```

Use MVVM Light (or some other way) to bind the SelectionChanged event to a command, or wire up an event handler for the SelectionChanged event.  In your Command (or event handler), get SelectedItem, and look at the first property (you didn't tell us what it was called, so I don't know what to call it).

Remember to make sure that SelectedItem is not null before you do anything, and, when you're done handling the command, set **SelectedIndex** to -1, so that they can select the same item twice, and still get the functionality to execute.

Comment: Thanks for replying =D 
This seem to be more generic since it attached to the class also. 
From what i search online, mostly will be MVVM light ~ 
But it used the relaycommand >.<